# Spring cloud with zookeeper dependencies get NullException in the second vister

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-zookeeper

I have an application with the name

```
spring:
  application:
    name: /business/paysystem-service
```

and I setting the client with the configuration

```
spring:
zookeeper:
  dependencies:
    PayService:
      path: /business/paysystem-service
```

so I can set feign client annotation with this name

```
@FeignClient(value = "PayService")
```

now I get a NullException when I visit the `FeignClient` the second time.

My springcloud version is Finchley.SR1

I push the complete code to github:https://github.com/kanghouchao/sample-springcloud.git

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace?

Comment: there is : 
        https://github.com/kanghouchao/sample-springcloud/blob/master/client/src/main/resources/the_errors_stack_trace.html

Comment: @spencergibb  You may be able to get more information from this issue：https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-zookeeper/issues/179 thanks lot

Comment: Can you please close one of them, I'd rather not try and keep two issues open.

Comment: ok, I closed that one

Comment: Finchley is built with curator 4.x. I can't guarantee it will work. Can you try with Edgware.SR5? Edgware is not compatible with boot 2.0 though. I'm not sure you have a compatible set of dependencies.

Comment: I know,but curator 4.x is not compatible with zookeeper 3.4.x.So I changed curator's version to 2.12.0

Comment: @spencergibb I modified the version of springcloud and changed it to your recommended Edgware.SR5, but the problem still remains unresolved. I still reported the same error, the stack information is at the original address, I updated it, and the updated code I submitted.  My update process is: replace the springcloud version with Edgware.SR5, replace the springboot version with 1.5.13.RELEASE, and then modify the feign import package error. After launching, click the second time I the same error as before.

Comment: And I submitted the error when I started using the curator 4.x when the project started, at: https://github.com/kanghouchao/sample-springcloud/blob/master/client/src/main/resources/the_boot_error_stack_trace_with_curator4 .x.html

Comment: @spencergibb I solved the problem and submitted the code. After finishing it, I found that I didn't add actuator on the server side. When I added spring-boot-starter-actuator, it worked fine.

Comment: @spencergibb I also added actuator in Finchley before, but because of an infinite loop dependency at startup, I removed the actuator dependency on the server side (because my server has mybits)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

首先我更换了springcloud版本，从Finchley改到Edgware.SR5，同时springboot更换到1.5.13.RELEASE。
然后我在server端添加了spring-boot-starter-actuator依赖，运行正常了

First I changed the springcloud version from Finchley to Edgware.SR5 and springboot to 1.5.13.RELEASE. Then I added the spring-boot-starter-actuator dependency on the server side and it works fine.

Comment: 再还原到Finchley，那个问题依然存在  
Then revert to Finchley, the problem still exists